# Pythonic method of returning a string of lists that come from a class

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, class

Class `A` contains a list of type class `B`, which contains a print function.  I am trying to return a String of all of the printed elements in `B`, separated by a new line.  What is the Pythonic 'single-line' way for method `GetList()`?

```
class A():
    # .....
    def GetList(self):
        temp = ""
        for item in self.ListOfTypeClassB:
            temp += item.Print() + "\n"
        return temp
```

I can add the newline to the print method if that makes it cleaner.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with classes really. You are concatenating a series of strings, it doesn't matter where those came from.

Comment: `return '\n'.join([item.Print() for item in self.ListOfTypeClassB]) + '\n'`.

Comment: That is true, I did not know if adding the additional information would help.  I can remove all of the related class information if you think that makes the question more specific.

Comment: I've already linked you to a duplicate; use `str.join()`, and the method calls can be done in a list comprehension passed to that method.

Comment: Thank you Martijn (and Kevin) for the super fast answers.  I actually had looked at that thread but over-thought it because I was making class calls.  This website is a lifesaver.